# Routing with avoid area and geofence / polygon

Tags: here-api, here-routing

I want to avoid specific streets when using the routing API. I have data points to create a geofence or polygon to represent those specific streets.
The router API accepts only up to 20 bounding boxes. I tried to send 20 avoid area bounding boxes to represent the road, but the result is not reliable (e.g. on diagonal roads).

Is there a way to send a geofence/polygon instead of bounding boxes?
Or any other way to avoid certain streets?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `avoid[segments]` instead of `avoid[areas]` for avoiding specific roads. In the case of having too many roads to avoid, you can also put the `avoid[segments]` parameters into request body and send a `POST` request to the same endpoint.

In order to get the `segmentId` of the roads you would like to avoid, you can do a normal routing call with parameter `spans=segmentId` added and then look at the `topologySegmentId` attributes in `spans` section of the response.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the avoid[segments] suggestion. It seems to work good, but I could not find a reliable way to determine the segmentId.

By using the normal routing with spans=segmentId, not all streets are covered by routing. I have a list of points(lat,lng), which I want to avoid.

I tried to use reverse geocoding, but it returns a pointadress, like here:xs1:pointaddress:9845050

Answer (score 1):

HERE Routing API now supports polygons for avoid area, https://www.here.com/learn/blog/routing-supports-polygons-for-avoid-areas

Answer (score 0):

You have to make below calls for your usecase.

1>Rest call to get segmentId For the route.

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes? apikey={your_app_id}& origin=32.834496,74.81515& destination=32.811632,75.816037& return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions& spans=segmentId& transportMode=car&

2>Rest Call to get the get Route with avoid[segments]

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes? apikey={your_app_id}& origin=32.834496,74.81515& destination=32.811632,74.816037& return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions& spans=segmentId& transportMode=car& avoid[segments]=here:cm:segment:808368834,here:cm:segment:808095972